# edit 2 models with one view and controller cakephp

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.3

I have 2 models. Typology and TypologyPicture. and 2 controllers Typologies and TypologyPictures. I want to edit both  typology and typologyPcture from one controller.

```
<?php echo $this->Form->create('TypologyPicture', array('type'=>'file')); ?>
<legend><?php echo __('Edit Typology Picture'); ?></legend>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('id'); ?>
<!-- Here is the first part for the update Typolohgy -->
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Typology.item_id',array('empty'=>true)); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Typology.title'); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Typology.description');?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Typology.thumbnail',array('type'=>'file')); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Typology.typology_category_id',array('empty'=>true)); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Typology.typology_condition_id',array('empty'=>true)); ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->input('Typology.price',array('placeholder'=>'Price')); ?>
<!-- Here is the second part for the update Typpology Picture -->
<?php echo $this->Form->input('pic_path', array('label'=>'Picture','type'=>'file'));  ?>
<?php echo $this->Form->end(__('Submit')); ?>
```

This is the view. which contain the field for typology (item_id|title|description|thumbnial|typology_category_id|typology_condition_id)
and the field for typologypictures (pic_path)

The controller (that is at TypologyPicturesController) is:

```
public function edit($id = null) {
    if (!$this->TypologyPicture->exists($id)) {
        throw new NotFoundException(__('Invalid typology picture'));
    }
    if ($this->request->is(array('post', 'put'))) {
            if(empty($this->data['TypologyPicture']['pic_path']['name'])){
                unset($this->request->data['TypologyPicture']['pic_path']);
              }
        if ($this->TypologyPicture->saveAll($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The typology picture has been saved.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The typology picture could not be saved. Please, try again.'));
        }
    } else {
        $options = array('conditions' => array('TypologyPicture.' . $this->TypologyPicture->primaryKey => $id));
        $this->request->data = $this->TypologyPicture->find('first', $options);

        $opt =  array('conditions' => array('Typology.id' => $this->request->data['TypologyPicture']['typology_id']));
        $this->request->data = $this->Typology->find('first', $opt);

    }


    if ( AuthComponent::user('role')==='admin' ||AuthComponent::user('role')==='superadmin' ){ //if the user is admin or superadmin, show all on dropdown
            $items = $this->Typology->TypologyItem->find('list');
        } else {// else if the user is author, show only item created by him.
            $items = $this->Typology->TypologyItem->find('list', array('conditions' => array('TypologyItem.user_id' => AuthComponent::user('id'))));            
        }
    $typologyCategories = $this->Typology->TypologyCategory->find('list');
    $typologyConditions = $this->Typology->TypologyCondition->find('list');
    $users = $this->Typology->TypologyUser->find('list');
    $this->set(compact('items', 'typologyCategories', 'typologyConditions', 'users'));

    if ( AuthComponent::user('role')==='admin' ||AuthComponent::user('role')==='superadmin' ){
        $typologies = $this->TypologyPicture->ItemTypologyPicture->find('list');
    } else {
        $typologies = $this->TypologyPicture->ItemTypologyPicture->find('list', array('conditions' => array('ItemTypologyPicture.user_id' => AuthComponent::user('id'))));
        }
    $this->set(compact('typologies'));
}
```

And when i try to edit, it opens the form, the fields are filled properly, but wheni press save there is new row inserted at typologyPicture and no change at all to Typology.

So what i want is that when the user press submit only the correspondings rows are updated  and not to insert new rows.....

Comment: I supose your `Topology` hasMany or hasOne `TopologyPicture` and therefore you should create `Topology` form instead and edit the data in `Topology` controller.

Comment: YES @skywalker  typology hasMany TypologyPicture, and TypologyPicture BelongsTo Typoogy. As for creating the form  is there like a specific way i should follow to create that form?

Comment: No specific way, it's just natural to edit topology with image not the other way around. You can have edit for images then you only have to have select for Topology id in that form.

Comment: yes @skywalker i have the edit for images, and you just select the typology this images belongs to but i wanted to achieve something more user friendly to incorporate typology and typologyPicture in one form and edit them there. with one view and one controller...but i just cont get the right way to access the data..:/

Comment: Then create form for topology controller and fetch all data there and pass it to view where the form is. You can edit it there and save in topology controller.

Comment: Try `saveAssociated()` instead of `saveAll()`.